# Problem in Python with function only writing one line to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function in Python 3 that will write all lines that end with the string 'halloween' to a file. When I call this function, I can only get one line to write to the output file (file_2.txt). Can anyone point out where my problem is? Thanks in advance.

```
def parser(reader_o, infile_object, outfile_object):
    for line in reader_o:
        if line.endswith('halloween'):
            return(line)

with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file_input:
    reader = file_input.readlines()
    with open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
        file_output.write(parser(reader))
```

Comment: Not very sure but is it because u r using return and not write?

Comment: Why not pass the output to the parser method and replace return(line) with output_file.write(line) ?

Comment: @Bogdan I don't think that's a good idea. One method should be responsible for finding the matches, another for writing the files, if you're going to split it up. If you're going to have the function do the writing, it should just do everything, like in the generator expression version of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def parser(reader_o):
    for line in reader_o:
        if line.rstrip().endswith('halloween'):
            yield line

with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file_input:
    with open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
        file_output.writelines(parser(file_input))
```

This is called a [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators). It can also be written as an expression instead of a function:

```
with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file_input:
    with open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
        file_output.writelines(line for line in file_input if line.rstrip().endswith('halloween'))
```

If you're on Python 2.7 / 3.2, you can do the two `with`s like this:

```
with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file_input, open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
```

You don't need to do `readlines()` on the file, just telling the loop to iterate over the open file itself will do the exact same thing.

Your problem was that `return` always would exit the loop on the first match. `yield` stops the loop, passes out the value, then the generator can be started again from the same point.

Comment: Thank you! `yield()` solved my problem. I really appreciate your thorough answer and detailed explanation. You also taught me a few other cool things like the two `with`s statement. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`line.endswith('halloween')` might only work on the last of a file, since all other lines will have a newline appended. `rstrip` the line first. Also, use `yield` instead of `return`.

```
if line.rstrip().endswith('halloween'):
    yield line
```

Note that this will also strip off spaces at the end of the line, which may or may not be what you want.

You'll also have to modify your consumer to

```
with open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
    for ln in parser(reader):
        file_output.write(ln)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your parser function should be a generator. At the moment it's only called once and returns the first line that has "halloween" in it.

Like the following:

```
def parser(reader_o):
    for line in reader_o:
        if line.endswith('halloween'):
            yield line

with open("file_1.txt", "r") as file_input:
    with open("file_2.txt", "w") as file_output:
        file_output.writelines(parser(file_input))
```